# HTML input - multiple patterns's join not working

Tags: html, validation, design-patterns

I have the below section in my HTML,

```
<input type="text" #version tabindex="1" class="form-control" id="version" name="version" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="application.version"
                                    required minlength="1" pattern="\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}.\d{1,4}|\d{1,3}.\d{1,4}.\d{1,4}">
```

Basically, I want the pattern of my variable to meet either of the following 3 patterns:

- 1.0
- 1.0
- 1.0.0

However it seems the join "|" doesn't work here. The wrong pattern like "1.abc.def" will still be validated successfully. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. It works like below:
((\d{1,3})|(\d{1,3}.\d{1,4})|(\d{1,3}.\d{1,4}.\d{1,4}))

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this:

This will match pattern like `1.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.0`

```js
var str = "1.0.0";
        if (/^\d{1,1}\.\d{1,1}\.\d{1,1}$/.test(str) || /^\d{1,1}\.\d{1,1}$/.test(str) || /^\d{1,1}$/.test(str)) {
    alert("matched");
} else {
    alert("not matched");
}
```